# How to interpret the identity function in this formula?

Tags: exponential-distribution

I am confused by the identity function notation in a formula:

$f(y|\theta)= \theta\cdot e^{-\theta\cdot y}I_{(0, \infty)}(y)$

Could someone help me understand what $I_{(0, \infty)}(y)$ means in the formula?

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$I_{(0,\infty)}$  is the "indicator function" or "characteristic function" of the set $(0,\infty)$.  It takes the value $1$ if its argument is in the set $(0,\infty)$ and $0$ otherwise.  You might write $$I_{(0,\infty)}(y) = \begin{cases} 1&\text{if $0<y<\infty$}\\0 & \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

Comment: Ahh! So does it mean I calculate the part before the indicator function, and plug the result to the indicator function, in order to decide I keep the result or make it 0?

Comment: Yes.  Calculate the part in front of the indicator and multiply it by the value of the indicator. It does not matter which of the two quantities you work out first.